# Identify if a given expression is a general solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the following expressions:
$$
\text{(i)}: \lambda(x; x_0,y_0) = y_0 \cosh(x - x_0) \\
\text{(ii)}: \lambda(x; x_0,y_0) = y_0 \tan^2(x - x_0) \\
\text{(iii)}: \lambda(x; x_0,y_0) = (3[x^2 - x_0^2] + y_0^3)^{1/3}
$$

I would like to find out if these expressions are general solutions for an ODE.

Here are some ideas :

1. Checking if the initial condition $\lambda(x_0; x_0,y_0) = y_0$ is satisfied.

We observe that (ii) does not satisfy the initial condition. Indeed we have $\lambda(x_0) = 0 \neq y_0$. Therefore, (ii) is not a general solution of an ODE.

2. Checking the differentiability of these expressions.

We observe that for $x_0 = y_0 = 0$, (iii) is not differentiable in $x = 0$. Therefore, (iii) is not a general solution of an ODE.

What else could I check (in particular to verify if (i) is a general solution) ?

Comment: What kind of ODE is the question. (iii) is at least differentiable in lots of points. Could it be a solution there?

Comment: For (ii) I agree.

Comment: There are no hypothesis on the ODE (or I don't understand your question ?)